# What is the future of Gazebo on a sans-OpenGL macOS?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Since Apple deprecated OpenGL and OpenCL for the current OS already, it is not unlikely that the next version will remove support for these technologies altogether. Apple wants developers to use Metal.

My question is if there is a way forward for Gazebo if this becomes a reality.
Is there e.g. a way to make use of Metal or keep using a OpenGL version that is implemented in user land and/or has an abstraction layer on top of metal?
I think it is important to know for people who rely on macOS and think about working with Gazebo/Ignition in the future.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22570/what-is-the-future-of-gazebo-on-a-sans-opengl-macos?/) by [Mr Seppersburg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6063/mr-seppersburg/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We now have a homebrew formula for ogre2.1 that has both metal and OpenGL on macOS 10.14 (mojave), but osrf/gazebo doesn't support ogre2. Unless support is added, osrf/gazebo 7, 9, and 10 will not work on macOS 10.15 where OpenGL support is expected to be removed. We are planning to add support for metal in ignition-rendering and will look into porting this over to osrf/gazebo.

Edit: I've created an issue to track this at https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2630/opengl-deprecated-in-macos-1014

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2019-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr Seppersburg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6063/mr-seppersburg/) on 2019-05-19**:
Thank you so much! Good to know that this is already on your plate. Will make sure to check back on that issue before upgrading macOS (IF they abbandon OpenGL).